# Calculate function out of 4 Points (Java)

Tags: java, function, math, graph

Is there any package in Java which can return a mathematical function if you insert 2, 3 or 4 points?

Like this:

```
p1 (0,2)
p2 (1,6) (Maximum)
p3 (2,1) (Minimum)
p4 (3,5)
```

The function should be just an approximation which goes through all points.

Comment: Why not just create the function.

Comment: I guess, you mean a **linear regression**, right?

Comment: @arias_JC Can you provide a example?

Comment: @Syntac yeah something like that. I need to provide this for multiple point arrays so doing it by hand is not an option.

Comment: @Herget what do you mean with "*prove*"? You may want to tell us, what your exact problem is and what criteria the method has to forfill.

Comment: If you are trying to find a polynomial formula that matches these points, you can use matrices.

Comment: @Syntac sorry corrected my comment - meant to write *provide*.

Comment: @Herget need more details if you want any kind of example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know any, but Im thinking of easily writing one for linear equations :

```
public String function(Point p1, Point p2) {
    String formula;
    Point p3; //Gradient
    p3.x=p2.x-p1.x;
    p3.y=p2.y-p1.y;
    double gradient=p3.y/p3.x; //Gradient per x
    double add=p1.y-gradient*p1.x;
    if (add != 0) {
        formula=Double.toString(gradient)+"x+"+Double.toString(add);
    }
    else {
        formula=Double.toString(gradient)+"x";
    }
    return formula;
}
```

assuming you have a Point class which looks like this :

```
class Point {
     double x,y;
}
```

Edit :

Other solution : Use a sinus/cosinus function squeezed enough to fit all points : [image]

Note :

> Its only getting hard if points are defined it isnt allowed to pass